# How to generate hex sequence in Swift?

Tags: swift, hex

Hey guys I am trying to create a tool to calculate how many 6 bytes sequence it generates within a certain time set by me, like 10s or 1min and so on. The sequence, for example, is: 4F B0 33 47 A3 BC.

So it's hex numbers and each 6 bytes all together must be unique and would start from 00 00 00 00 00 00 to FF FF FF FF FF FF.

So the problem is that I can't figure out how I could set the counter to go like from 0 to F and do all the possible combinations.

All I know is that it can't be done randomly because it can generate duplicates during the process and as I said it must be unique 6bytes sequence.

So any one have any idea on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Six bytes represent positive numbers in the range from zero, inclusive, to 2<sup>48</sup>, exclusive<sup>*</sup>. Each of these values can be uniquely converted to a sequence of six bytes. All these values fit in `UInt64` type, so if you would like to generate all possible combinations, start at zero, and keep incrementing the counter until you reach `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

You can do the conversion to a hex sequence in many different ways - for example, you could use shifts and bitwise operators to "cut out" each byte, and formatting it as a hex value.

* Other interpretations are possible, too, but positive numbers in the range from `0` to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF` is good enough for the purposes of this task.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida Yes, if you do not mind having your combinations be sequential, it would. If you want to randomize them, you could do that too, but you would need to keep a hash set of combinations that you have seen previously.

Comment: Well since sequential would achieve the same goal I want which is to evaluate the amount of generated numbers in a given time, as doing it randomly, I think it's less code going sequential. What do you think?

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida I think sequential means not only less code, but also a lot less memory.

Comment: Be aware that 6 bytes is, as @MarcoAlmeida says, 22^48. That's 281,474,976,710,656.  >281 **TRILLION** possible values. If you're generating hex strings out of those, each hex string takes 17 characters. At 1 byte per character in ASCII, that's 4.785*10^15 bytes of data (4,785,000,000,000,000) maybe more if you have line breaks.  4,785 **TERABYTES** of output. 4.75 **petabytes**.

Comment: Yes @DuncanC but since I just want to measure the time it takes for a certain amount way way way more less reaching the end it won't be a problem.